# Android FrameLayout position using Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framelayout

[image]

I am adding a fragment with:`getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_host, TutorialFragment_.builder().build(), "tutorial").commit();`

the FrameLayout is inside a RelativeLayout using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/phone_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/phone_tutorial"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tuto_image_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:src="@drawable/a_capacity" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tuto_image_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/a_loan_simulation"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tuto_image_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/a_checklist"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:src="@drawable/add_btn_circle_center"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_host"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/mButtons"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mButtons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:visibility="visible">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.bnpf.androidnative.core.view.FontButton
            android:id="@+id/next_tutorial"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/Generic_Button_Next"
            android:textColor="@color/processStepCategoryTextColor" />

        <com.bnpf.androidnative.core.view.FontButton
            android:id="@+id/skip_tutorial"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="@string/Generic_Button_Cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/processStepCategoryTextColor" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The TutorialFragment object uses this layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/tutorial_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

No matter what I try, this FrameLayout is always aligned on top of the screen, and I need it to be at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: add this `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: thanks @User_1191 but no luck... it doesn't work

Comment: i have posted answer, do you try that?

Answer (score 1):

Try by change your layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:visibility="visible" >
.....

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_host"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/mButtons"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relLayout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
```

Now view pager will come below 'relLayout' and above 'mButtons'

Comment: This fixed my problem. Now can you explain me why I need to specify above and below at the same time? Isn't just one supposed to be enough? tanks for the help

Comment: by default viewpager will take match_parent if you don't fix boundries

Comment: If you want to give wrap_content to view pager, I have added one more answer check it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your RelativeLayout is not full screen,so the FrameLayout will never aligned the bottom of the screen

Comment: Actually it is, because I have a LinearLayout already positioning at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: try set the viewpager height to match_parent

Comment: also the LinnerLayout should be match_parent too

Comment: I also have tried to put every concerned layouts to android:layout_height="match_parent" with no luck...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
   <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/tutorial_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post screenshot of  your result

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this also:

```
public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager {

public MyViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    // find the first child view
    View view = getChildAt(0);
    if (view != null) {
        // measure the first child view with the specified measure spec
        view.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec, view));
}

private int measureHeight(int measureSpec, View view) {
    int result = 0;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

    if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        result = specSize;
    } else {
        // set the height from the base view if available
        if (view != null) {
            result = view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            result = Math.min(result, specSize);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

in xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/mButtons"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relLayout"
    android:background="#0000ff" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_host"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```